# K2—load Items and Categories by ID

Tags: k2, model

I am about to write a little plugin for K2 what enables the user to link Items/categories to items/categories. The backend part is working and I would like to load the items/categories in

```
public function onK2PrepareContent(&$item, &$params, $limitstart) {}
```

I have tried to load an Item like that:

```
private function loadItem($iid)
{
    if(!isset($this->itemCache[$iid]))
    {           
        $oid = JRequest::getInt('id');
        JRequest::setVar('id', $iid);

        $item = $this->itemModel->getData();
        $this->itemModel->prepareItem($item, 'item', '');

        JRequest::setVar('id', $oid);   
        $this->itemCache[$iid] = $item;
    }
    return $this->itemCache[$iid];
}
```

But that throws some errors and seems not to work properly. Any Ideas I can load the Items and Category Objects?

Thanks in Ahead!

Comment: What errors it throws? What do you mean about "not working properly"?

Comment: Are you getting errors while displaying the items in the frontend or while creating the links in the backend? I suppose this is supposed to be like a redirect plugin for K2?

Comment: This is an old one… The »little« Plugin became a big Plugi so the code to post is too much for here… With »linking« I mean, to append Items on one page. I finally made it work, all issues are gone.